# how to jquery parse array in elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, json

I have a problem about parse data json, ajax.

Example:

```
<div class="row" id="order-list">
    1. Latte <input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="1"/>
    <div class="extra">
        +ice <input type="hidden" name="extra[]" value="2"/>
        +bigger <input type="hidden" name="exra[]" value=3"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="order-list">2.pizza<input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="2"/>
   <div class="extra"></div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="order-list">
   3.Cocoa <input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="3"/>
   <div class="extra">
        +ice <input type="hidden" name="extra[]" value="2"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

how to parse data like

```
type:["1","2","3"],
extra:[["2","3"],[],["2"]]
```

Comment: Whats Your Exact JASON Structure ?

Comment: extra:[["2","3"],[],["2"] has syntax error

Comment: Do you Mean extra:[["2","3"],[],["2"]] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, according to your question it is very hard to give direct answer. There are more simple answer than this but I can't figure out what you exactly need. Try form serialize() as well.

```
<html lang="us">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        function getData()
        {
            var typeArray = new Array();
            var extArray = new Array();

            $.each($(".row"),function(key,val){
                var extra = new Array();
                typeArray.push($(val).find(".type").val());
                $.each($(val).find((".extraInput")),function(k,v){
                    extra.push( $(v).val() );
                });
                extArray.push(extra);
            })

            var retObj = {};
            retObj.type = typeArray;
            retObj.extra = extArray;
            return retObj;
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            alert( JSON.stringify(getData()) );
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="row" id="order-list">
        1. Latte <input type="hidden" class="type" name="type[]" value="1"/>
        <div class="extra">
            +ice <input class="extraInput" type="hidden" name="extra[]" value="2"/>
            +bigger <input class="extraInput" type="hidden" name="exra[]" value="3"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="order-list">2.pizza<input class="type" type="hidden" name="type[]" value="2"/>
        <div class="extra" ></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="order-list">
        3.Cocoa <input type="extraInput" class="type" name="type[]" value="3"/>
        <div class="extra">
            +ice <input class="extraInput" type="hidden" name="extra[]" value="2"/>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for .serializeArray(). http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/

Comment: I use $('div#order-list :input').serializeArray(); it not working

Comment: Well maybe you can paste your JS aswell then.

Comment: You have to wrap your dom into a form then use $("#formId").serialize()

Answer (score 0):

Try This Buddy:

```
var types=$('input[name="type[]"]').map(function(E){
    return E.value;
});

var extra=$('.row').map(function(E){
    return $(E).find('input[name="extra[]"]').map(function(E){return E.value}))
});

var data={"types":types,"extra":extra}
```